# MongoDb duplication eror on insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am inserting the documents in mongod db colletion

every time triggerdate  and event will change, but if insert them continuously with any time gap we are getting mongo duplication error.

but if we are doing insertion with time back it's getting inserted.

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 
     var msgObj = {
      "event" : "Password expired",
   "assignee" : "Test",
      "triggerDate" : "06/21/2018 18:44:27", }
 var url  ="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/org_democustomer"
           for( var i=0; i<300;i++){
         
              MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                  var connection = db;
                   var collection = db.collection('events');
                    // Insert all customer's tickets into document
                  collection.insert(msgObj, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                     connection.close();
                 });
            });
    }
```

so, how ObjectId creation is?
is it based on time?
error is

> MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:
> org_mssdemocustomer.testalerts index: *id* dup key: { :
> ObjectId('507f191e810c19729de860ea') }

How can I generate unique id for immediate insertions

Comment: In your code you are hard-coding the ObjectId to a fixed string, so of course you get duplicates. Can you post the correct code, please? If this is the code you are running simply remove the string and let ObjectId compute an id on its own!

Comment: Why do you need to create ObjectId on your own? Mongo client can do it for you.

Comment: You can `ObjectID();` to generate one if you have to. [implementation here](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js)

Comment: without object id also it is same error,  see modified code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectId value. The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:

- 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- 3-byte machine identifier,
- 2-byte process id, and
- 3-byte counter,starting with a random value.

Here is your code which is working fine.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
var msgObj = {
    "event": "Password expired",
    "assignee": "Test",
    "triggerDate": "06/21/2018 18:44:27"
}
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    //var connection = db;
    //var collection = db.collection('events');
    var dbo = db.db("org_democustomer1");
    // Insert all customer's tickets into document
    msgObj._id = new ObjectID();
    dbo.collection("events").insert(msgObj, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}
db.close();
});
```

Comment: drop your collection and run the script again.

Comment: It is the same , might be the object id create based time stamp, so it is giving the same id , if trying to insert

Comment: I have made few changes. Works fine now. Refer the code.

Comment: Cool. Your assumption was right about same ObjectID.